# Hide all instances of a class except for the one clicked

Tags: jquery, html

My HTML sets up like this.

```
<div id="A" class="square channels blue">A</div>
<div id="B" class="square channels blue">B</div>
<div id="C" class="square channels blue">C</div>
```

What I want to do is get the `id` for the `class` that was selected...like this:

```
$('.channels').click(function() {
alert(this.id ) //This gets me the right `id`
});
```

Now what I want to do is hide all the other instances of "channels" classes, but show (i.e., not hide) the one that was selected. In other words, hide all the instances of the class "channels" except for the one that was clicked on.

This doesn't work obviously, but not exactly sure how to do this:

```
$('.channels').click(function() {
    $('.channels').hide();
   $(this.id).show();
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the ***.not*** selector:

```
$('.channels').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.channels').not(this).hide();
});
```

The example:

```js
$('.channels').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.channels').not(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="A" class="square channels blue">A</div>
<div id="B" class="square channels blue">B</div>
<div id="C" class="square channels blue">C</div>
```

Comment: Hadn't even remotely thought of this! I like this one.

Comment: I like this solution the best because it seems a little inelegant to hide all, then show the one that was clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

I think this

```
$("#" + this.id).show();
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
$('.channels').click(function() {
    $('.channels').hide();
   $("#"+$(this).id).show();
    });
```

Without #, it will not use id.

Comment: I don't see why the construct `$("#"+$(this).id)` would be used.  Why not just  `$(this)` like in other examples?  Has the additional benefit that the elements don't need IDs.

Comment: You don't need id for the solution. But he needs to know the mistake he is doing.

Comment: @AnilM   Thanks...the additional insight is helpful. Didn't know I could just do `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Even this solution will work

```
$('.channels').click(function() {
   $('.channels').hide();
   $(this).show();
});
```